# Finding eigenvectors and eigenvalues of an operator in quantum mechanics

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quantum-mechanics

I'm reading this book about quantum mechanics.  The author wants the reader to do the following exercise:

> Find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the operator
>   $$A = \pmatrix{\cos \theta & \sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & -\cos \theta} .$$

He says to use the following trial eigenvector and find $\alpha$ in terms of $\theta$:

$$|V\rangle = \pmatrix{\cos \alpha \\ \sin \alpha} .$$

I found the eigenvalues: $λ_1=+1$ and $λ_2=-1$ for the spin, but I can't seem to find the eigenvectors in the book:

$[ \cos(θ/2) ; \sin(θ/2) ]$ for $λ_1=+1$

$[ -\sin(θ/2) ; \cos(θ/2) ]$ for $λ_2=-1$

I get completely different eigenvectors, which work but the ones above work too.  He then uses those vectors to find the probability of getting $+1$ state:

$P(+1) = ([1 0]\times[ \cos(θ/2) ; \sin(θ/2) ])^2$
$P(+1) = (\cos(θ/2))^2$

any help for finding these eigenvectors?

EDIT: I get the following eigenvectors:

$[ \cotθ-1 ; 1 ]$ for $λ=-1$
$[ \cotθ+1 ; 1 ]$ for $λ=+1$

Comment: I've formatted the first few display equations for readability; you can format the remainder by the emulating the $\LaTeX$ code I've written.

Comment: *I get completely different eigenvectors, which work...*  It might help us to help you if you tell us what you are getting, and how you are getting it.

Answer (score 0):

As you know if $$Av=\lambda v,$$ then also for $w=\alpha v$ you'll get
$$Aw=\alpha Av=\alpha\lambda v=\lambda w$$

Particularly, for your case, one of eigenvalues may look like 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 \cot t+\csc t\\1
\end{pmatrix}
$$then
$$
\sin\frac{t}{2} 
\begin{pmatrix}
 \cot t+\csc t\\1
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
 \cos\frac{t}{2} \\\sin\frac{t}{2} 
\end{pmatrix}$$

With the second it is very similar.